# Call internal pages with drupal_http_request

Tags: 7

I'm writing a little module, and I need to call several pages of my site using `drupal_http_request()`, which accepts only absolute URLs.
I don't want to add a variable to store the domain of the site, also because on my company we have proxy etc.

Which is the best way to add the domain of the site?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean exactly, but have you looked at [`global $base_url`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7) ?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal Answers. I guess you want the absolute URL of the web server from which you call `drupal_http_request()`. Is  there any reason why you cannot use `url('', array('absolute' => TRUE))`? Did you try it?

Comment: If my page is "page" and I try to run
`$url = url('page', array('absolute' => TRUE))`, `$url` seems to be `http://default/page`.

Comment: I can use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] but I don't know if works always..

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I'm using in a similar situation, with $base_url as Baysaa mentioned above.

```
$path_to_file = '/path/to/feed.xml';
$base_url = $GLOBALS['base_url']; // Not sure if this line is necessary.
$file_over_http = $base_url . $path_to_file;
$http_result = drupal_http_request($file_over_http);
```

Comment: I think you can use `GLOBAL $base_url` as well.